# What is the most concise way to source a file (only if it exists) in Bash?

Tags: bash, error-handling, include

In Bash scripting, is there a single statement alternative for this?

```
if [ -f /path/to/some/file ]; then
    source /path/to/some/file
fi
```

The most important thing is that the filename is there only once, without making it a variable (which adds even more lines).

For example, in PHP you could do it like this

```
@include("/path/to/some/file"); // @ makes it ignore errors
```

Comment: Important reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450239/why-check-for-file-existence-before-sourcing-it

Answer (score 46):

Is defining your own version of `@include` an option?

```
include () {
    [[ -f "$1" ]] && source "$1"
}

include FILE
```

Comment: This doesn't work as expected if the sourced script refers to its positional parameters. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151889/why-does-bashs-source-command-behave-differently-when-called-from-a-function). I wonder why no one points this out for good 8 years.

Comment: Do you mean if something like `include FILE a b c` being equivalent to `source FILE a b c`?

Comment: I don't see how you think the first argument woudl be doubled, unless you are writing `source "$1" "$@"`. As for why I didn't use `"$@"`, it simply wasn't necessary for the original question as stated.

Comment: This is what I'd like to say: [https://repl.it/repls/LightblueTriangularLoopfusion](https://repl.it/repls/LightblueTriangularLoopfusion) (online editor)

Comment: That's fine. It doesn't really have much to do with this question, though, which never mentioned any need to pass arguments to the file to be sourced.

Comment: No. It's important even for this question. The problem is an additional argument is passed if or not that's needed. That can be disastrous: [https://repl.it/repls/ProfitableInsecureCallback](https://repl.it/repls/ProfitableInsecureCallback)

Answer (score 18):

If you're concerned about a one-liner without repeating the filename, perhaps:

```
FILE=/path/to/some/file && test -f $FILE && source $FILE
```

Comment: If `set -ex` is set beyond your control (in a build environment, for instance), this is the answer you want.

Answer (score 13):

If you are concerned about warning (and lack of existence of sourced file isn't critical for your script) just get rid of the warning:

```
source FILE 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: The file is optional so lack of it is to be expected, but doesn't this also discard any output the included script generates?

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom: Yes, but it will only discard any output sent to the standard *error* by the script. Any output sent to standard output by the script will come through fine.

Answer (score 6):

You could try

```
test -f $FILE && source $FILE
```

If `test` returns false, the second part of `&&` is not evaluated

Comment: Slighly better, but I'd prefer to have $FILE only once (updated the question)

Comment: Since it's a variable, its value will be consistent, I don't think you should concern yourself with it

Comment: That's it though, it's not necessarily a variable

Comment: You can assign the name to a variable, and then you reduced the problem to one where my answer is a solution (so you don't repeat the file name)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to always get a clean exit code, and continue no matter what, then you can do:

```sh
source ~/.bashrc || true && echo 'is always executed!'
```

And if you also want to get rid of the error message then:

```
source ~/.bashrc 2> /dev/null || true && echo 'is always executed!'
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the shortest I could get (filename plus 20 characters):

```
F=/path/to/some/file;[ -f $F ] && . $F
```

It's equivalent to:

```
F=/path/to/some/file 
test -f $F && source $F
```

To improve readability, I prefer this form:

```
FILE=/path/to/some/file ; [ -f $FILE ] && . $FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not concerned with the output of the script, you could just redirect standard error to `/dev/null` with something like this:

`$ source FILE 2> /dev/null`